# Is there a way to hide some installs output from CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

I'm installing huge directories with CMAKE using

```
install(FILES ....)
```

**I'm wondering if there was any way to hide/skip specific lines**, because they're usually Up-to-date and i'm having large outputs of this hiding relevant informations.

```
Up-to-date: ....
```

If not, i'll find some workarounds with Batch scripts but i'd really like it to be in the CMakeLists.txt

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE` variable for that.

Adding `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE LAZY)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` would skip the "Up-to-date" messages.

See [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html) for further information.